# var mqtt = require('mqtt'); that shows syntax error

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi

i am following this tutorial regardign saving data to database using mqtt to mysql [sensor to mysql via mqtt](http://ediy.com.my/blog/item/143-store-messages-from-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-into-sql-database) where i am at the app_mqtt.js part where i try to follow the exact same thing to create the js file but when i try to run it via python, it shows an error of :

```
File "app_mqtt.js", line 1
var mqtt = require('mqtt'); 
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have already the mqtt via `npm i mqtt` and `npm install mqtt --save` yet it still have such an error, i really need help in this. Thank you.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var Topic = '#'; //subscribe to all topics

var Broker_URL = 'mqtt://192.168.1.123';

var options = {
    clientId: 'MyMQTT',
    port: 1883,
    keepalive : 60
};

var client  = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL, options);
client.on('connect', mqtt_connect);
client.on('reconnect', mqtt_reconnect);
client.on('error', mqtt_error);
client.on('message', mqtt_messsageReceived);
client.on('close', mqtt_close);

function mqtt_connect()
{
    console.log("Connecting MQTT");
    client.subscribe(Topic, mqtt_subscribe);
}

function mqtt_subscribe(err, granted)
{
    console.log("Subscribed to " + Topic);
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
}

function mqtt_reconnect(err)
{
    console.log("Reconnect MQTT");
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    client  = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL, options);
}

function mqtt_error(err)
{
    console.log("Error!");
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
}

function after_publish()
{
    //do nothing
}

function mqtt_messsageReceived(topic, message, packet)
{
    console.log('Topic=' +  topic + '  Message=' + message);
}

function mqtt_close()
{
    console.log("Close MQTT");
}
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Python...

Answer (score 0):

As per your code , it shows fine.

1) Try to restart the server.

2) check your code to this code

```
npm i mqtt --save

var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://{Your connection string}')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
 // message is Buffer
 console.log(message.toString())
 client.end()
})
```

3) At last , re-install the package.

Note: If still issue , please share your code. So I can debug it.

Comment: hi, i've tried restarting and reinstall via npm install reinstall -g but it it still not working. i'll update the code in my post

Comment: @Kelvin Please share your full code. Now in your current code there is no var mqtt. :(

Comment: so sorry about it! There's something wrong with the formatting! I have edited already thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Kelvin Can you please try to comment your all MQTT code and just put my code and check still you getting syntax error ? If not showing then just set your remaining code there.

Comment: @Kelvin Try to uninstall package with `sudo npm remove mqtt -g` instead of `reinstall`.